# detect unit tests that took long time to respond

Tags: unit-testing, testing, xunit, .net-7.0, dotnet-test

i'm new to unit testing , i have a lot of unit tests, how can i find tests that took long time to respond ?

i try this:

```
dotnet test -l "console;verbosity=detailed"
```

its good but i need to filter the tests than take more than 2 milisec!

1- how to filter the tests that took more than 2milisec?

2- additionally , do you know a command line or any external tools that help me to create a report like that? (for example : a tools to generate some report that show some metrics and analysis )

thanks a lot

Comment: Is it because you don't want the testing process to take a long time? Or is it because you want to test that the main program code runs fast enough? If the latter, perhaps you should, rather than use unit testing, formally measure the speed, by running the code thousands or millions of times in a loop, with varying data, and average the run times.

Comment: for continues integration , we write 'dotnet test' command in a docker file , we create azure pipeline that execute it and create some usefull reports like code coverage and etc. i'm looking for find a way to find more metrics and analysis base on our unit tests

Comment: additionally  , do you know any good external tools to  measure the speed and performance and some extra metrics ? for example : a tools that generate some metrics and performance metrics reports